# PHP... If "shared" is ticked there is no error but if left unticked Undefined Index notice

Tags: php, html

```
$shared = (isset($_POST['shared']) ? $_POST['shared'] : null);
if (isset($_POST['shared'])) 
{
    $_POST['shared'] = implode(',', $_POST['shared']);     
}
 $message .= "<tr><td style='background: #eee;'><strong>Shared Drive/s :</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['shared']) . "</td></tr>";


    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[0]" value="K:"> K:  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[1]" value="L:"> L:  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[2]" value="M:"> M:  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[3]" value="N:"> N:  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[4]" value="O:"> O:  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[5]" value="P:"> P:  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[6]" value="Q:"> Q:  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[7]" value="R:"> R:  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shared[8]" value="S:"> S:  <br>
```

If "shared" is ticked the form submits successfully if its not ticked i get an undefined index notice. Im new to PHP...

Comment: checkboxes are not sent over form data if they are not checked.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Way**: Use variables like this `$value = isset($_POST['value']);`

**2. Way**: put this code top of page `error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );`

```
$shared = isset($_POST['shared']);
if ( $shared ) {
    $shared = implode(',', $shared );     
}
 $message .= "<tr><td style='background: #eee;'><strong>Shared Drive/s :</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($shared) . "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: what does the 2 way do? Does it just cover up the issue?

Comment: yeah. this is not exactly issue, just notice. most of coders using 2.way